# Symfony2.5 softDeleted with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine

How to make the symfony doctrine extension 'SoftDeleted' works with mongoDb? (doctrine-mongo-odm). The plugin says 'only works for ORM'...And is there any other solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions) for ODM currently doesn't support Softdeletable.

> List of extensions which support ODM
>
> - Translatable
> - Sluggable
> - Timestampable
> - Blameable
> - Loggable
> - Translator
> - Tree (Materialized Path strategy for now)
> - References
> - Sortable

See the documentation on Github for more informations.

**Edit**: scratch that. Just found this https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/pull/877

**Edit 2**: https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/SoftDeleteable/Filter/ODM/SoftDeleteableFilter.php
It seems to work like the normal ORM annotation. To set it up with symfony just follow the usual documentation (not the one on that Repo).

Config:

```
doctrine_mongodb:
...
    document_managers:
        default:
            [.....]
            filters:
                soft-deleteable:
                    class:             Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\ODM\SoftDeleteableFilter
                    enabled: true
```

**Edit 3** Updated the code above again, because I'm stupid

Comment: Yes i know, it's the reason why i'm asking if there is another solution ? (i'have edited my post)

Comment: @user2733521 updated my answer. Should work, not tested since I currently don't have a Mongo running here.